# Distributing load among threads using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have 1500 records to delete and 5 threads to delete them.

I want to make sure that every thread will delete only 300 records.

How can I achieve this using JMeter script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define by a simple [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 300 value as Loop Count:

> Loop Count Number of times to perform the test case.

And 5 value as *Number of Threads*

> Number of Threads Number of users to simulate.

Comment: By keeping loop count as 300 , I can be sure that each thread will execute test case 300 times  so total 5 X 300 = 1500.Is it right??

Comment: @swapna yes, but notice that still you can have errors